# How to make a div draggable and come back to its original position on drag end

Tags: jquery, drag, movable

Is it possile using jquery to make a div draggable in such a way that it comes to its original position when the drag end.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI's Draggable.

See this demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#revert

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.